# How can I have keyword argument from string parameter?

Tags: python, string, parameters, arguments

I want the `field_name` to be inputted from string. Is this a possibility in Python?

```
earliest = Model.objects.filter(
    field_name__year=latest_datetime.year,
    field_name__month=latest_datetime.month,
    field_name__day=latest_datetime.day
).order_by(field_name)[0]
```

I hope this function will give you a little but explanation on what I want.

```
def cool_function(field_name_from_param):
    earliest = Model.objects.filter(
        field_name_from_param__year=latest_datetime.year,
        field_name_from_param__month=latest_datetime.month,
        field_name_from_param__day=latest_datetime.day
    ).order_by(field_name_from_param)[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct a `dict` and use `**` for [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), e.g.:

```
def cool_function(field_name_from_param):
    earliest = Model.objects.filter(
        **{field_name_from_param+"__year": latest_datetime.year,
           field_name_from_param+"__month": latest_datetime.month,
           field_name_from_param+"__day": latest_datetime.day}
    ).order_by(field_name_from_param)[0]
```